# JQueryUI Datepicker in my asp.net mvc View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have this code in my view.

```
 $("#Effective Date").datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonText: "..."
            });
```

I am able to see the the date and I can select the date. But when I open the datepicker Iam not seeing the Arrows on the popup box. `<< <  March 2012 > >>`

can anybody please help me out

Comment: see my tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be something to do with the CSS you're using.

Here is a jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/C9rCT/

It uses jQuery 1.7, jQuery UI and links to the jQuery UI CSS file from Google (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css)

Comment: +1 - part payment for the hint re the radio button javascript question today that i picked up and ran with after your suggestion!! oh, and your answer is also the most correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you also have the CSS and images from the jQuery you downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

These 'arrows' are backround image. Check the css.